# Selecting only active records django query

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework

In my Django project, I have an `is_active` boolean column in every table of my database. Every time I or the framework accesses the database, I want only the active records to show up. What is the standard way to achieve this? Certainly I don't want to check for `is_active` in every queries I make.

Comment: use model managers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a custom model manager, like this:

```
class OnlyActiveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(OnlyActiveManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)
```

Then, add it to your models:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    active = OnlyActiveManager()
```

Next, use it like this:

```
foo = MyModel.active.all()
```

You can also use it to replace the default manager (called `objects`), but then you'll have to do custom queries to get all records that are in-active.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a manager class for your model, A sample model manager is given below, for more you can refer Django official website

```
class MediaManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MediaQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def active(self):
        return self.filter(is_active=True)

class Media(models.Model):
    (..model fields..)
    objects = MediaManager()
```

The query should be like

```
media = Media.objects.active()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using django model managers.

please check django documentaion for detail [django documentaion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset)